# Accurate signal delay calculation in Python

Tags: python, signals, lag, correlation

I'm trying to calculate the lag between two signals in Python using cross correlation. The two signals are almost identical except for a very small timelag. I've tried numpy.correlate and scipy.convolve (alot faster) and both works relatively well but gives a small error. I'm starting to suspect that the error is the result of Python/scipy/numpy truncating a float somewhere. Has anyone been able to get high accuracy signal delay calculations working in Python?

Best regards
Fredrik

Comment: "a small error"? How small?  How much noise is in your source data? "truncating a float"?  Usually that leads to epic errors, not minor errors.  Without any more data, we can only guess.  I guess that your Intel chipset has a broken FP processor.

Comment: Well, the error is in the range of < 0.01% of true lag. We're currently doing some tests with numpy.longdouble troughout the code.

Comment: when you say "very small" what is the value relative to the sampling interval?

Comment: if it is not proprietary, can you share with us how you find the time lag. I am stuck with a similar issue, and using numpy.correlate or fft/multiply/ifft approach is giving me wrong answers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the power spectrum of the two signals you do get a small error due to the fact that the cross correlation is not properly normalised at each lag. Here is a little function that I use; it normallises the overlap region at each lag and I found it gives accurate results:

```
def NormCrossCorrSlow(x1, x2,
                  nlags=400):
res=[]
for i in range(-(nlags/2),nlags/2,1):
    if i<0:
        xx1=x1[:i]
        xx2=x2[-i:]
    elif i==0:
        xx1=x1
        xx2=x2
    else:
        xx1=x1[i:]
        xx2=x2[:-i]
    res.append( (xx1*xx2).sum() /( (xx1**2).sum() *(xx2**2).sum() )**0.5)
return numpy.array(res)
```